# Weird performance results

Tags: c++, performance

I have a generated lexer. The lexer takes a callback in a parameter and calls it each time a match is found. Callback's prototype is:

```
void(const char *matchBegin, const char *matchEnd, unsigned matchId);
```

I am testing it with two callbacks:

Empty callback:

```
[] (const char *, const char *, unsigned)
{}
```

Incrementing counter callback:

```
[&counter] (const char *, const char *, unsigned id)
{
    counter += id;
}
```

Here are the measurements for 100MB of input (there is no difference between programs except those callbacks):

`gcc   5.2      empty calback: Avg: 582.3ms, StdDev: 11.3ms (run 20 times)`

`gcc   5.2 increment callback: Avg: 396.6ms, StdDev: 1.68ms (run 20 times)`

`clang 3.7      empty calback: 402ms`

`clang 3.7 increment callback: 577ms`

My intuition is that additional increment operation should cost us time. Apparently it does not in case of gcc. Can anyone explain why?

**EDIT:**
@Joachim: The lexer accepts any function object in a parameter:

```
template <typename M, typename Action>
inline void tokenize(const M &stateMachine, const char *&begin,
    const char *end, Action action);
```

The time is measured automatically by gtest. Exactly one test is run. The state machine generation is not taken into account.

Comment: I'm a little curious about that callback, I assume it's a `std::function` object? Because otherwise you would not be able to use the capturing lambda.

Comment: Now about the timing results, did you test it only once? A few times? A million times? Is it an average? How loaded was the system you ran te tests on? *How* did you check the time? Was optimization enabled?

Comment: @Joachim:
The lexer accepts any function object:
`template <typename M, typename Action>
inline void tokenize(const M &stateMachine, const char *&begin,
    const char *end, Action action)`

The results are always the same (modulo a few millis).

Comment: I've had unintuitive results once, too. The increment will be very fast (possibly undetectable due to pipelining); suddenly other factors are more important like code alignment which changes (to the better) with an additional instruction.

Comment: My suspicion is that the difference will vanish once you profile properly. A one-off different of a few milliseconds means nothing: this isn’t a reliable benchmark. You need properly quantify the standard deviation first.

Comment: You are compiling with -O3 and no -g, right? Show us the compiler flags.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Its compiled in Release mode in cmake on linux. The flags:
`-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -DNDEBUG`

Comment: It'd be good to provide your full benchmark source (and in MCVE form). For a start, do you output the counter variable at the end? If not, the optimizer is likely to optimize away that useless instruction, though it should never cost much at all anyway to really show up as a substantial diff. Also do you just parse the exact same string each time? If so, the increment version which is being run after the empty version might be benefiting from temporal locality, while the empty version is suffering compulsory misses. One crude/quick way to check that is to swap the order of your tests.

Comment: @Ike 1. The code of the generator is too long to paste here but I'll see if I can cut it. 2. Yes I do output the counter to stdout. 3. Both tests are run in separate processes.

Comment: That's awesome (I mean for me -- makes this question much more interesting)! More info would be much appreciated, as I want to see an answer! It would be amazing if this was attributed to something as obscure and micro as instruction alignment.

Comment: @piotrekg2 did you ever find out what the cause was?